# I am trying to build and install this driver but failing

Tags: make

I have followed the INSTALL directions and say these

```
    ./autogen.sh
    make
    make install
```

I have succeed executing the ./autgen.sh but when im typing make this error comes:

```
make:*** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

the driver im trying to install is 
ScanGear MP Ver. 1.90 for Linux (Source file) (PIXMA MX894 )

Comment: Please provide more details in the question, i.e. the actual installation manual (an URL will do, or excerpt from the docs you got with the driver) and possibly, the source of the driver (most likely an URL again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical instructions should be:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

`configure` creates a Makefile, so without `configure` Make cannot do anything.

Are you shure you want to really use this driver?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually some libraries were missing and now all working find. For readers, always check the error messages